# Nginx redirect to PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx, phantomjs

I am attempting to redirect to a phantomJS instance running on port 8888. However it is failing. The regular page loads, but when I change the #! for the ?_escaped_fragment_= it just gives me the regular page still...

Excerpt from the nginx file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        if ($args ~ _escaped_fragment_) {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/?_escaped_fragment_=/;
        }

        #mi angular app
        server {
        location / {

                root /var/www/html/miwebapp/client/app;

        }
        }

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution found at the bottom of this ["crawlable application" post on senior-java-developer.com](http://senior-java-developer.com/ajax/crawlable-application) shows how to address the issue by rewriting to another location that handles the proxy_pass as follows:

```
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=(.*)") {
  rewrite ^ /snapshot${uri};
}   
location /snapshot {
    proxy_pass http://api;
    proxy_connect_timeout  60s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My working configuration:

```html
if ($args ~ _escaped_fragment_) {
    rewrite ^ /snapshot$uri;
}

location ~ ^/snapshot(.*) {
    rewrite ^/snapshot(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
}
```

More info here: https://github.com/liuwenchao/ajax-seo